# Position of particular item in the listview

Tags: android, listview, position

I have a listview with a lot of variables (about 1000). How can I get the position of a particular string variable (eg "Washington")?
That is, I want to say how knowing the name of the variable (name of city) to get its position in the listview.

Comment: You can look/iterate in the source (array, Cursor, hash ...) you use to feed the adapter of the listview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the `ListAdapter` that you're using.  If you have an `ArrayAdapter` and a simple array of strings the code would be something like:

```
ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = (ArrayAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
int position = arrayAdapter.getPosition("Washington");
```